# Set default language for sudo

Tags: sudo, language-support

If I enter a command, the output is translated in the language I am using on the system. But if I use `sudo` to run a command with root privileges, the output is always in English. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

But there is a workaround:

- If you haven't already done so, go to *System Settings -> Language Support* and click the "Apply System-Wide" button.
- Get root privileges using `sudo su`

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#sudo_caveat

Comment: @EliasEx: Sounds dangerous. Nothing I would try.

Comment: How can I change the global local variable in the console? I need this for a server with out an UI.

Comment: @EliasEx: `/etc/default/locale` is intended for setting the locale globally.